# Swift: create an array of dictionaries of any objects

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to create an array which elements are dictionaries which keys are strings and values are AnyObject. This is my code:

```
var informationOfRows: Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> = [
        ["title": "Mis Promos", "icon": FontAwesome.Money, "segue": "myPromoSegue"],
        ["title": "Mis Marcas", "icon": FontAwesome.Briefcase, "segue": "myBrandSegue"],
        ["title": "Editar Perfil", "icon": FontAwesome.Edit, "segue": "editUserProfileSegue"],
        ["title": "Invitar Amigo", "icon": FontAwesome.EnvelopeO, "segue": "inviteFriendSegue"],
        ["title": "Quejas y Sugerencias", "icon": FontAwesome.LightbulbO, "segue": "suggestionSegue"]
    ]
```

However, I am getting an error message that states: **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.**

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

P.S.: Fontawesome is a library which contains a bunch of icons.

Comment: Can you add the declaration for `FontAwesome` here?

Comment: It is just an enumeration which definition is `public enum FontAwesome: String`.

Comment: There comes your problem: `String` is a value type, not object type, so it doesn't conform to `AnyObject`. Swift 1.2 gave a better error message than 2.0 on this. Change your dictionary to `<String, Any>` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, if you want you can provide an answer, and I can mark it as valid. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FontAwesome` is an enum of type `String`:

```
public enum FontAwesome: String { ... }
```

`String` is a value type, not object type, so it doesn't conform to `AnyObject`. Swift 1.2 gave a better error message than 2.0 on this. Change your dictionary to `<String, Any>` instead:

```
var informationOfRows: Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = ...
```